# url rewrite for seo optimization and google referencement

Tags: php, mysql, regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a catalogue.php file that has links through a mysql query (row) to a works.php file. The same thing in French (sommaire.php to oeuvres.php). $img is the title in a table column and $i loops through rows and gives a number.
The link is created like this:

```
<? echo "<p><a href='work--".StandardizeString($img)."_".($i)."' >  
$img</a></p>";
$i++;
?>
```

I then have a rewrite rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^oeuvre--(.*)_(.*)$ oeuvres.php?&tittle=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^work--(.*)_(.*)$ works.php?&tittle=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

This creates a url *sitename/work--title_linenumber*
I would like the url to be *sitename/title_linenumber* or ideally *sitename/title* being that title is unique for each directory.
I have spent many hours trying to strip the row number but to no avail so I am ready to give that up. That is why I put it at the end. But I would like *work--* to disappear.

Comment: Why not simply output the link you want from php and avoid dealing with rewrites?

Comment: I'm intrigued. Have no idea how to rewrite mysql queries to urls without mod rewrite. I will also look into this solution tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: Ignore my last comment. So you're trying to do a bilingual site? And you're trying to remove the id?: You want `mysite.com/work/title-of-work` and `mysite.com/oeuvres/title-of-work` ?

Comment: Yes, ideally no ID in the url. At the moment, each 'artist' has a subdirectory where the php files are stored. So the ideal url is 'mysite.com/artist/name-of-the-work. What I have for the moment is mysite.com/artist/work--name-of-the-work_id.com or the word 'oeuvre' instead of 'work' for the French version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rules should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)_(.*)$ works.php?&tittle=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: How would this rule distinguish between works.php and oeuvres.php? If a also use RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)_(.*)$ oeuvres.php?&tittle=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA] won't there be a conflict?

Comment: Thanks. I will try to move my php files to separate folders, French in one, English in another, so that I can use your solution. I will post my results tomorrow

Comment: I realized that without the word 'work' or 'oeuvre' I could have duplicate urls (same name in French and English and same row number). So I have decided to make the url mysite.com/artistname/work__work-name__00. Last question: anyway to get rid of that hideous trailing row number? I made my work-name column with a Unique Key but impossible to link to it without the row number

Comment: Yes `mysite.com/artistname/...` is a good idea. Also but I didn't get your question about `hideous trailing row number`. Can you provide some example to explain what change you want in the rules?

Comment: I would love the row number to be stripped: mysite.com/artistname/work__work-name. I have tried several times but I can never get the url to resolve correctely.

Comment: It can be done but need some clarity like some examples of URIs with row number that you want to strip down to: `mysite.com/artistname/work__work-name` ? Also like to know what this URI: `mysite.com/artistname/work__work-name` should be rewritten to?

Comment: The actual URL is mysite.com/artistname/work__work-name__worknumber. The php file that generates the link is found in the /artistname folder. The work-name is a mysql field in the column [engleg]. The worknumber is generated by the looping $i (i++) which generates a 'catalogue' list. The mysql query is "$sqlNum = 'SELECT * FROM artisname order by engname ';" and the link generated by the htaccess is <a href='work__".StandardizeString($img)."__".($i)."' >. My [engleg] column has a Unique Key so I think I can link to it using something like <a href='work__".StandardizeString($img)."' >.

Comment: See If URL doesn't have `worknumber` your script will not get it and you will need to query database by `work-name` which is far from efficient. Look at Stackoverflow URL of this question: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357982/url-rewrite-for-seo-optimization-and-google-referencement/` where they have question id and question title both. IMO this is the best pretty URI scheme.

Comment: OK I will validate this answer.